# How do I add a language to a notebook in Beaker?

Tags: beaker-notebook

I'd like to add a language like to my Beaker notebook. How to I know which languages are available to add, and how do I add them?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Notebook menu to open the Language Manager. There are buttons for each possible language. Each button has a status indicator: gray means inactive, green means active, and yellow means it is in progress of starting up. Click on the language you want to add (one that is gray). It should turn yellow, and after a while, depending on how fast your computer is, it should go green. Close the manager, and then when you open the language menu on any cell, you can set it to the new language and run it.